# C nested structs in correlation

Tags: c, struct, declaration

I have the following code:

```
#define MAX_VIDEOS 100

typedef struct video_t {
    int likes;
    int dislikes;
    char* title;
    user_t* uploader;
} video_t;

typedef struct user_t {
    char* username;
    char* password;
    video_t videos[MAX_VIDEOS];
} user_t;
```

I want to use `user_t` in `video_t` and vice versa.

In every case, `gcc` just says `"unknown type name"`:

> youtube.c:9:5: error: unknown type name ‘user_t’
>
> ```
> user_t* uploader;
>   ^
> ```

which is normal, but I can't think of a way to solve this problem.

Comment: you need to declare them beforehand (as prototypes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *forward-declare* `user_t`:

```
#define MAX_VIDEOS 100

typedef struct user_t user_t;

typedef struct video_t {
    int likes;
    int dislikes;
    char* title;
    user_t* uploader;
} video_t;

typedef struct user_t {
    char* username;
    char* password;
    video_t videos[MAX_VIDEOS];
} user_t;
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the fast answers, it solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: Isn't forward-declare a bit misleading here? I'd say _define_.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: it's [not a *definition*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration). It's a *forward-declaration* + `typedef`.

Comment: Right, but `user_t` is defined (as a result of typedef), I'm not talking about `struct user_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Forward declare the `user_t` type-alias:

```
typedef struct user_t user_t;
```

After that you can use `user_t *uploader` in the `video_t` structure.

Answer (score 1):

Move the type definition for the missing type at the beginning. This makes sure compiler is aware of the *type* while it is being used.

Something like

```
 typedef struct user_t user_t;
```

and then, later, just declare the structure, the `typedef` is already there.

at the beginning of the shown snippet can solve the issue. In this way

- While declaring `struct video_t`, `user_t` is already known and the typedef `video_t` is defined.
- While declaring `struct user_t`, `video_t` is known.

So, both end meets.

Answer (score 1):

The first `struct` doesn't know the signature of `user_t` (declare it forward)

Change to

```
#define MAX_VIDEOS 100

typedef struct user_t user_t;

typedef struct video_t {
    int likes;
    int dislikes;
    char* title;
    user_t* uploader;
} video_t;

struct user_t {
    char* username;
    char* password;
    video_t videos[MAX_VIDEOS];
};
```